# Rendering a table from 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have 2 arrays.
One with wanted table columns `scheme = ['username', 'email', 'created'];`
The second with the data:

`data = [{ username: "...", email: "...", created: '...', gender: '...' }, {...} ...];`

I want to render a table like this:

```
username     email     created
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
...          ...       ...
```

I'm using handlebars with express in node.

Comment: What code have you tried? :)

Comment: That sounds great. Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Why 2 arrays? you only need one, the one with the data. Then, you loop  through the array and create your HTML from there.

Comment: @frenchie you need to store the order of the table columns somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it :). The key was to use the handlebars helpers. Writing a helper is really easy. So here is mine:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');

hbs.registerHelper('getByKey', function(data,key) {
    return data[key];
});
```

(don't forget, im in nodejs).

So after i have the helper and have the data array full of objects and i know the names of the properties i want here is the end code:

```
<h1>List data</h1>

    <table class="table" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><b>id</b></td>
                {{#each scheme.listDisplay}}
                    <td><b>{{this}}</b></td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        </thead>

        {{#each data}}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{id}}
            </td>

            {{#each ../scheme.listDisplay}}
                <td>{{#getByKey ../data this}}{{/getByKey}}</td>
            {{/each}}

        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you. Just insert this script wherever you want your table to be.

```
var header = ["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"];
var content = [["blah", "blah", "blah"],["ha","ha","ha"]];

document.write("<tr>");
for (i=0;i<header.length;i++) {
    document.write("<td>"+header[i]+"</td>");
}
document.write("</tr>");

for (i=0;i<content.length;i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (f=0;f<content.length;i++) {
        document.write("<td>"+content[i][f]+"</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: That's okey but i want to use handlebars. :)